# Limiting behaviour of state vector under delayed (open-loop) inputs

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, control-theory, linear-control

Given a discrete-time LTI system as $$x_{i+1} = A x_{i} + B u_{i}$$ and suppose the feedback law $u_{i} = \mathcal{K}(x_{i})$ assymtotically stabilizes the closed-loop system. Now, consider the modified (i.e. delayed) input law $u_{i} = \tilde{\mathcal{K}}(x_{i-I})$ for some constant (but possibly unknown) $I \gg 1$ (e.g. 10). Given an initial condition $x_{0}$, what can I see about whether there exists some $i$ such that $\Vert x_{i} \Vert \geq \rho $? Does the state norm grow beyond some bound, given enough time? And does this depend on $A$ being (Schur) stable?

---

My intuition (and simulation) says that the state trajectory will eventually leave any finite set (regardless of $A$ being Schur ), as we are basically injecting an arbitrary input into the system, which is not related to the current state. Thus, the system is running in open loop. However, how do I prove this, or at least make this more mathematically rigorous? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: state]

**P.S.** This is related to *replay attacks* in control systems which I'm investigating.

Comment: A trivial counter example would be $A=0$, or $A$ Schur and $\mathcal{K}()=0$. Also note that this system is still completely deterministic, at least I assume that the delay $I$ is (maybe unknown) but constant?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems that you think 'delayed' = 'random'. This is not the case, as mentioned by @KwinvanderVeen . Also you ask 'does this depend on $A_i$ being (Schur) stable', but your system has constant $A$ matrix (no index $i$). Which one is correct? Also if you have a feedback control, you must check the matrix of the closed loop system (maybe you meant that?). Finally, does the notation $u_i=\mathcal{K}(x_i)$ mean that the control is nonlinear? Or did you actually mean $u_i=\mathcal{K}x_i$? If it is nonlinear, what is the specific reason for not using linear control here?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Good point, I'm assuming neither $A$ nor $\mathcal{K}$ are trivial (i.e. 0). Yes you're right, the system is indeed deterministic, so maybe I could rewrite the error dynamics somehow introduced by the delay $I$? I'm not quite sure how though..

Comment: @SampleTime You're right, I've removed the word random. The system is time-invariant, that was a typo, apologies. The feedback law $\mathcal{K}$ is linear, but not necessarily full-state feedback: there might be additional LTI controller dynamics. But if the full-state feedback assumption simplifies the dynamics, then that's a start

Comment: With the question as stated, there is no notion of probability. With fixed delay $I$, it is either stable or unstable. Unless the random variable is the delay $I$ itself (delay is unknown, fixed but sampled from some distribution). Which I can see making some sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: In the case of constant delay equal to $I$ and linear full-state feedback map $x\mapsto Kx$, you can rewrite the system in an augmented form considering a new state $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times (I+1)}$ , defining $y(k)=[x(k), x(k-1), \dots, x(k-I)]$. Then the closed loop is a discrete-time linear system (but on a space of larger dimension, and with a system matrix much more ``sparse''), whose stability can be analyzed with standard tools. Of course, as you noted, even if $A+BK$ is Shur stable, in general the delayed system can be unstable.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza you're right, I've edited the question title.

Comment: @MatteoDR Ahh yes, thank you so much, that's a very promising direction! I suppose these results can be extended to output feedback and dynamic controllers, but the dynamics become a bit more involved (having to keep track of previous controller states/outputs)? And lastly, do you know how one could prove instability for these time-delay systems? So far, I've only found Lyaponuv-based sufficient conditions for stability. Thanks!

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel For a constant delay, you can simply check the instability of the augmented system to prove the instablity of the delay discrete-time system. This amounts to checking whether the matrix of the augmented system is Schur stable.

Comment: @KBS Thanks! As a follow-up, say for some $I$ the matrix is not Schur Stable: does this imply it is not Schur stable for any $I' \geq I$ (i.e. can I prove this holds?)

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel Not necessarily. This will be system dependent.

Comment: My previous comment contained a typo, sry for that, I meant of course large delay is *not* the same as open loop (maybe in the limit if you have infinite delay, you could think about it like that, but this is in practice not too interesting i guess). Here the corrected comment: One more comment since you edited the title of the question: delayed is not the same thing as decoupled. Also, large delay is not the same thing as open loop. If you have Matlab you might take a look at the allmargin function, it computes the delay margin of a given LTI system with negative feedback.

Comment: So essentially you have a closed-loop system, where the input samples of the state are delivered to the controller with a nondeterministic delay? I've extensively studied this topic in grad school, and in general there aren't tractable ways to determine the stability of the overall system using analytical control theoretic methods. Moreover, stability largely depends on what the time-delay distribution is (I've written about this in my thesis if interested). You may have luck with [CQLFs](https://mural.maynoothuniversity.ie/6234/1/OM-Common-Quadratic.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your controller is linear, then you can rewrite the closed-loop system into the form

$$z(k+1)=M_0z(k)+M_dz(k-d)$$

where $d$ is the constant delay. The state $z$ will contain here the state of the system and that of the controller.

The above system can be rewritten as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z(k+1)\\
\hline
z(k)\\
\vdots\\
z(k-d+2)\\
z(k-d+1)\\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[\begin{array}{c|cc}
M_0 & 0_{n\times n(d-1)} & M_d\\
\hline
I_n  & 0_{n\times n(d-1)} & 0_{n\times n}\\
0_{n(d-1)\times n} & I_{n(d-1)} & 0_{n(d-1)\times n}
\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}
z(k)\\
\hline
z(k-1)\\
\vdots\\
z(k-d+1)\\
z(k-d)\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The stability of the above system can be established by looking at the stability of the matrix, which is turn equivalent with the stability of the time-delay system.

When the time-delay $d(k)$ is time-varying with an upper bound of $\bar d$, then the system rewrites as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z(k+1)\\
\hline
z(k)\\
\vdots\\
z(k-\bar d+2)\\
z(k-\bar d+1)\\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
Q_0(k) & Q_d(k)\\
\hline
\begin{array}{c}
I_n\\
0_{n(\bar d-1)\times n}
\end{array}
  & \begin{array}{cc}
0_{n\times n(\bar d-1)} & 0_{n\times n}\\
I_{n(\bar d-1)} & 0_{n(\bar d-1)\times n}
\end{array}
\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}
z(k)\\
\hline
z(k-1)\\
\vdots\\
z(k-\bar d+1)\\
z(k-\bar d)\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $Q_0(k)=M_0+M_d$ if $d(t)=0$, $M_0$ otherwise, and $Q_d(k) = e_{d(k)}^T\otimes M_d$ for $d(k)>0$, $0$ otherwise.

Then, this system can be analyzed using discrete-time LTV methods or switched systems methods. There are necessary and sufficient stability conditions for such systems, but they are difficul to apply. So, you will most likey have to turn to sufficient stabiliy conditions here.

Finally, when the delay is stochastic, time-varying, and evolves acording to a finite-state Markov chain described by $p(k+1)=p(k)\Pi$. The stability of the stochastic system can be anlyzed using the associated theory. Necessary and sufficient stability conditions exist.